# MultipeerConnectivity Memory Leak in receive method

Tags: swift, memory, memory-leaks, autorelease, multipeer-connectivity

I'm using **MultipeerConnectivity** Framework.
The application intends to send and receive large audio files constantly.

In the receiver, the memory is allocated indefinitely.

When I write this method,

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID){
     let usingData:NSData = autoreleasepool{
            return  NSData(data: data)
        }
}
```

Why does autoreleasepool  not seem to be effective and the memory not free?

Comment: A small amount of data is sent between, to secure the connection. Is it encrypted?

Comment: No, I use this session = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: MCEncryptionPreference.optional)

Comment: I m sorry the application send the data ,I delete the sentence "contents is nothing". I misuse.

Comment: It's sending small amounts of data to determine internal functions, not apart of your application. Might I ask why you desire thereto be zero data sent?

Comment: Memory for data received on the receiving side when intentionally transmitting data was secured.
After that, it is a problem that the secured memory is not freed forever.
For a small amount of data it is not a problem.

Comment: Corrected grammar and added tags.